# Types/Categories of rhyme?

Tags: poetry

By type in this case I mean ways of grouping rhyme.

*There are a number of ways to categorise rhyme, based on what element you're looking at.  for example masculine/feminine refers to the number of syllables, while family/Perfect refers to the sound type.  Here are the types I know about:*

**Sonic connection**: Perfect, Family, Assonance, Consonance,

**rhyme pair length**: Masculine, Feminine

**relational**: Additive, Subtractive

There are exotic types like the following

*Mirror Rhyme* - Pair sound opposite to each other, like Pool/loop, or Dare/Raid

I'm looking to get a list of rhyme types not included in the above list, 
Bonus points for exotic types similar to mirror rhyme.

Comment: I believe this is a question about study of the language, and as such, belongs to English.SE

Comment: I thought about that.  I've included it in both here, there, and on music.stack exchange because I think it's kinda on the fringes of all 3.    

I think it's pertinent here to poetry, and creating rhythm in writing passages.

Comment: [This page](http://quizlet.com/2149831/types-of-rhyme-uil-lit-crit-flash-cards/) has some terms of interest.

Comment: Even though the categorizing -- in and of itself -- is not of interest here, the existence of those categories probably is.  Someone searching for novel rhyme schemes for their poetry would benefit from this question.

Answer (score 4):

**Eye Rhyme:**   Rhyme on words that look the same but which are actually pronounced differently – for example “bough” and “rough”. The opening four lines of Shakespeare’s Sonnet 18, for example, go : 
      Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?
      Thou art more lovely and more temperate:
      Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,
      And summer’s lease hath all too short a date: 
Here, “temperate” and “date” look as though they rhyme, but few readers would pronounce “temperate” so that they did. Beware that pronunciations can drift over time and that rhymes can end up as eye rhymes when they were originally full (and vice versa).

**Rich Rhymes:**  Rhyme using two different words that happen to sound the same (i.e. homonyms) – for example “raise” and “raze”. The following example – a triple rich rhyme – is from Thomas Hood’s” A First Attempt in Rhyme” : 
      Partake the fire divine that burns,
      In Milton, Pope, and Scottish Burns,
      Who sang his native braes and burns.

**Slant Rhymes:** (sometimes called imperfect, partial, near, oblique, off etc.)
Rhyme in which two words share just a vowel sound (assonance – e.g. “heart” and “star”) or in which they share just a consonant sound (consonance – e.g. “milk” and “walk”). Slant rhyme is a technique perhaps more in tune with the uncertainties of the modern age than strong rhyme. The following example is also from Seamus Heaney’s “Digging” : 
      Between my finger and my thumb
      The squat pen rests; snug as a gun

All From [Daily Writing Tips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/types-of-rhyme/)

Comment: There is also analyzed rhyme, where consonance and assonance alternate in a quatrain; e.g., bit, mess, miss, bet. Arrangements like bit, bet, miss, mess are likely to be seen as just consonance, but may be appreciated after multiple quatrains. [Gratuitous link to my own (approximate) use of this type of rhyme](https://sites.google.com/site/paulclaytonplace/verse-works/romantic-verse#TOC-A-Courtly-Dream).